# SSRS: Grant access to users from a group to reports deployed (rsAccessDenied)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have deployed some reports. I have a user (among others) which is included in a group. I would like to grant access permission to all the users from this group to be able to execute report (to see the reports deployed). So from Reporting Services administrator page (http://localhost/Reports), I go to site configuration, then Security, and I click on new role assignment, I added the group with "System User" role.

Using a user that belongs to this group, I login into windows, then I open internet explorer browser, put the address:

```
http://ip:80/ReportServer
```

A window appear prompting a user and password. I enter one user that is administrator. Then a page with the reports deployed appears. Ok, I can see the reports deployed. So I click on one of them and I get the message error below:

```
Reporting Services Error

this report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter
```

Then I go to internet explorer options, and I add the address as trusted zone. Then reload the report and it works.

However, when I enter the address and use the user that belongs to the group (and it is not administrator) in the login page, an error is shown and the reports page does not appear:

```
The permissions granted to user 'domain\username' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)
```

I want to access these reports by using a Simple user account which has not administrator role. In that scenario how we can use this?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can the user in question access the underlying database? Do they have execute permissions on any stored procedure used by the report?

Comment: Do you mean the database on which report points to? Database is a SQL Server and this user and users belonging to that group are not grant to access the database but the report is configured with another user that is granted to access the database. I mean, reports datasets use another user that has access to the database. No problem to access database, the problem is to access and display the report. After entering address, and enter user/passwor in loging screen I receive rsAccessDenied.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like they aren't actually being given permission to the Report folders or the report itself. The Site Setting -> Security is only for accessing the report server's site itself. After that they need permission to the folders and reports. With an Admin click Fodler Settings and then Security. Add their security group to the folder and the report by default should inherit the folder's permission. If it doesn't work then check the report itself. To access the report's settings, you'll either need IE to open the dropdown in the folder view, or open the report in any other browser. After it loads in the upper left you should see Home > FolderName > ReportName. Click the report's name and it'll take you to it's setting page where you can change the security.

Comment: Ok, On monday I will check it at work. After applying security to the report folder and report itself, is it necessary to restart Reporting Services service?